# google calendar watch expiration time for more than one month?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I synchronize my CRM system with Google Calendar. To do that I ask for `push notifications` from my users Google Calendars into my system.
I have created a watch successfully and set the expiration time to year 2030, but when I receive a  response from the watch event, it shows the expiration time of the watch is set to one month.

Questions:

1. Does this mean I need to refresh the watch of each user's calendar in my system every month?
2. Is there a way to make the watch unlimited?

My Code:

```
$channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($client);
$uuid = gen_uuid(); 
$channel->setId($uuid); 
$channel->setType('web_hook'); 
$channel->setExpiration('1919995862000');
$address = $sugar_config['site_url'] . "/index.php?entryPoint=updateFromCal";   
$channel->setAddress($address); 
$watchEvent = $service->events->watch($bean->google_cal_id_c, $channel);
```

The response:

```
    [address] => 
    [expiration] => 1417667348000
    [id] => 87453668-b1fd-4468-beca-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [kind] => api#channel
    [params] => 
    [payload] => 
    [resourceId] => xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
    [resourceUri] => https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxx@gmail.com/events?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWHxxxxxxalt=json
    [token] => 
    [type] => 
    [modelData:protected] => Array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A notification channel can have an expiration time, with a value determined either by your request or by any Google Calendar API internal limits or defaults (the more restrictive value is used). Currently there is no automatic way to renew a notification channel. When a channel is close to its expiration, you must create a new one by calling the watch method. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) for more documentation about the notification channels.

Comment: The expiration time is set as 7 days by default. But it could be increased up to 1 month by request parameter. If the value is given more than 1 month, Google set it as 1 month by itself.

Comment: @Shanan how did you find out that the default expiration is 7 days and max 1 month? I can't find that in any of google's docs

Comment: @TyHitzeman 7 days is mentioned in [default value of params.ttl](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch?hl=en) which is 604800 seconds. The 30 days is not mentioned in the official documentation, but I experience such behaviour when I give more than 30 days as ttl value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Oauth and Service Account and use that instead to authenticate your Google Calendar Request:

1- Go to gcp, create a project, enable calendar api, create oAuth Account and create Service Account.

2- After creating oAuth, download the oAuth json file.

3- After creating the service account go to `keys` and create a new json key and also download. (You are going to use this one for authentication)

4- Go to the calendar you want to access with your api and add share the calendar with your previously created Google Service Account, set the permissions according to your needs

Done, now you can access the api without the need to refresh the token, nor create one. You just need to add the oauth json and the service account json in your files and call them when required. You should use the `jwtClient` to create your auth. All the rest should be the same.