# When Do Resource Watches Expire? | Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

What does Google Calendar's API use as a default `expiration` value for resource watches?

---

The GCal Node Client uses an expiration of 7 days when I don't pass it my own `expiration` value. Someone previously stated that the default is 7 days, and the max is 30 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790461/7781935)), but I haven't seen that verified in any official documentation.

Google Calendar API's [Push Notification doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#renewing-notification-channels) says that this `expiration` value for a resource watch is

> determined either by your request or by any Google Calendar API internal limits or defaults (the more restrictive value is used)

...but I haven't found where this "internal limit or defaults" value is officially documented.

---

I'm looking for a more official answer, because I don't want to have to set an unnecessarily quick `expiration` or have my sync code break if Gcal changes their default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch?hl=en) on Events Watch:

| `params.ttl` | `string` | The time-to-live in seconds for the notification channel. Default is 604800 seconds. |
| --- | --- | --- |

And as per Google:

[image]

NB: The same information can be found for [`Acl: watch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/watch?hl=en), [`CalendarList: watch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/watch?hl=en) and [`Settings: watch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/settings/watch?hl=en%7C).

Comment: I didn't connect the dots that `ttl` is effectively the same as `expiration`, thank you.